# Would you help me choosing the right answer for the following question?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, as, as-like

Which sentence is correct?

- a) How I was saying before being interrupted, being polite is mandatory...
- b) I got a promotion! Now I work like a production manager, with my own room and a personal assistant.
- c) Nothing new to report. Same like last week.
- d) That is not enough. To finish the job I will need at least three times as much.

**My thoughts:**

- a) is wrong. ' as I was saying ...' would fit better here.
- b) is wrong. 'I work as a productions manager, ...' sounds better.
- c) and d) seem correct to me.
- Which one would be the best option, c) or d) ?

Comment: Were you told to correct words or tenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four sentences are examples where "as" should be used.  (d) is the only one that uses "as", so it happens to be correct.

- a) **As** I was saying before being interrupted, being polite is mandatory...
- b) I got a promotion! Now I work **as** a production manager, with my own room and a personal assistant.
- c) Nothing new to report. Same **as** last week.
- d) That is not enough. To finish the job, I will need at least three times **as** much.

All four choices are examples of semi-formal speech.  They are all examples of things a "production manager" might say, either at work, or to his wife.  Choice (c) does not use full sentences, but it is a natural way to give a status report.  Unless the "production manager" is responsible for supervising a "room" in a factory or "boiler room", an American would say "my own office" instead of "my own room".